# DeadLock while sleep time are not the same with ReentrantLock

Tags: java, multithreading

The below code would cause deadlock:

```
public class IntLock implements Runnable {
    private static ReentrantLock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
    private static ReentrantLock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();
    int lock;

    public IntLock(int lock) {
       this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (lock == 1) {
                lock1.lockInterruptibly();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                lock2.lockInterruptibly();
            } else {
                lock2.lockInterruptibly();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                lock1.lockInterruptibly();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (lock1.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                lock1.unlock();
            }
            if (lock2.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                lock2.unlock();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " quit");
        }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       Thread t1 = new Thread(new IntLock(1));
       Thread t2 = new Thread(new IntLock(2));
       t1.start();
       t2.start();
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       t2.interrupt();
   }
}
```

but if I changed the sleep time in run method to the same, it would quit correctly or it would cause deadlock.I just wonder what's the difference between
the two code.

Comment: There is no deadllock here. A deadlock would be thread 1 holding lock A and trying to claim lock B while thread 2 holds lock B and is trying to claim lock A, or in general a circular chain of such. And a deadlock is permanent. What you have is a temporary lock.

Comment: but how could the program just suspend, does that means deadlock?Just confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since lockInterruptibly will receive interrupt signal. When you set 2000, the main thread first sleep 1000 milliseconds then call t2.interrupt(), t2 is still running Thread.sleep(2000), then InterruptedException will be catch by code

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

rather than

```
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (lock1.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            lock1.unlock();
```

So it will not release the lock.

Comment: well, does the 'finally' mean that it will be executed no matter what happended?

Comment: Of course , it will be executed.

Comment: So why it would not release the lock, I just released the lock in the `finally`

Comment: But in thread 1 you hold the lock1 acquire lock2, and in thread 2 you hold lock2 acquire lock1, this is a deadlock. The main thread break the deadlock by calling t2.interrupt(), which cause t2 resuming from waiting for acquiring the lock1, and release the lock2 which is hold by thread t2, so thread t1 will get the lock1. Then all of these thread will quit correctly.

Comment: Thank you.I get it.